# ¿Por qué Java le resta dos días a las fechas de SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc

En mi base de datos, en un campo de tipo *date*, tengo la fecha de... por ejemplo *`2017-07-15`* y al realizar un *select* hacia la tabla donde registro la fecha, la fecha concuerda con lo que ingresé, pero al querer obtener el valor de la fecha desde una aplicación de java, me aparece *`2017-07-13`* y en la base de datos aparece como *`2017-07-15`*.

¿Por qué sucede esto? ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Este es el codigo que utilizo para obtener el valor

```
String valorObtenido = "";
Statement st = cn.createStatement();
//le pasamos los resultados a una variable
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(consultaobtenervalor);
//mientras hayan resultados....
while(rs.next())
{
     //obtenemos el valor
     valorObtenido = rs.getString(ColumnaDelValor);
}
//cerramos las conexiones
st.close();
cn.close();
return valorObtenido;
```

`consultaobtenervalor` es la consulta select y `ColumnaObtenerValor` es de la column que tomaré el valor.

Comment: Me suena a una cuestión de zonas horarias, aunque es raro que la diferencia sea de más de un día. En todo caso recomiendo obtener el valor como un `Date` y no como un `String`, para tener más controladas las conversiones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No deberías confiar** en driver jdbc para convertir distintos tipos de datos de manera implícita. Esa conversión que el driver realiza al obtener como `String` una fecha es algo específico de su implementación, si deseas convertirla a String lo deberías hacer **explícitamente y luego de obtener la fecha con el tipo correcto**.

La clase `ResultSet` brinda diferentes métodos para obtener valores según distintos tipos de datos. En este caso conoces que la columna dada por el índice `ColumnaDelValor` (te recomiendo definir variables con notación [Camelcase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) para no confundir con clases) es del tipo `Date` por lo que deberías utilizar [getDate(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(int)):

```
 Date sqlDate = rs.getDate(columnaDelValor);
```

Este método retorna un objeto del tipo `java.sql.Date`. Si necesitas una instancia de `java.util.Date` puedes crearla a través de:

```
java.util.Date utilDate= new Date(sqlDate.getTime());
```

A su vez, si necesitas tener la fecha como `String`, utiliza [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Por ejemplo, si necesitas mantener tu fecha en el formato día/mes/año:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 String strDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en mi caso me restaba 1 día, pero obtenía los datos con getObject, lo que hice en la consulta es obtener el dato con getString, de esta forma no me restaba 1 día en la fecha.