# Porque java resta un día a la fecha obtenida de un executeQuery ejecutado a la base de datos almacenada en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, conversión-de-tipos, intellij-idea

Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos en ***MYSQL*** con 7 columnas llamada *tblAsegurados*, la cuál tiene una columna de tipo *DATE*, llamada *"Fecnac*".

Mediante ***MYSQLworkbrench***, ejecuto un query a la tabla de la manera siguiente:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblAsegurados ORDER BY Nombre, Nss"
```

Como resultado de éste query, se visualizan los registros con la informacion de mis columnas, en la que particularmente la columna tipo *DATE* denominada *"Fecnac"* muestra la fecha de manera correcta. Por ejemplo *"2018-12-31"* para el primer registro, *"2018-05-21"* para el segundo registro, etc. Ver la imagen:

[image: Ver imagen del resultado del query en ***MYSQLworkbrench***]

Ahora bien, elaboré una aplicación en java usando el IDE ***intelliJ IDEA*** que contiene un método para ejecutar el mismo query como a continuación se muestra:

```
public ArrayList<Asegurados> getAseguradosList(){
    ArrayList<Asegurados> aseguradosList = new ArrayList<Asegurados>();
    Connection connection = getConnection();
    var query = "select * from tblAsegurados order by Nombre,Nss";
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
        st = connection.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        Asegurados asegurado;
        while(rs.next()){
            asegurado = new Asegurados(
                    rs.getString("Nss"),
                    rs.getString("Nombre"),
                    rs.getString("Curp"),
                    rs.getBoolean("Esposa"),
                    rs.getInt("Semcot"),
                    rs.getInt("Hijos"),
                    rs.getDate("Fecnac"));
            aseguradosList.add(asegurado);

            System.out.println("Nombre:"+rs.getString("Nombre"));
            System.out.println("ASSIGNED VALUE IN THE CLASS:"+asegurado.getFecnac());
            System.out.println("QUERY DATE BY COLUMNLABEL:"+rs.getDate("Fecnac"));
            System.out.println("QUERY DATE BY COLUMNINDEX:"+rs.getDate(7));
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aseguradosList;
}
```

El "extraño" problema que pasa, es que el *query* ejecutado por la aplicación **"por sí mismo"** **me devuelve la fecha con un día menos**, es decir, muestra "2018-12-30" en lugar de "2018-12-31" y así sucesivamente con todas las fechas de los registros de la tabla.

Véase la siguiente imagen que refleja el resultado de mi aplicación en la consola del IDE.

[image: Imagen del query ejecutado en la aplicación]

Como información adicional, la clase "Asegurado" que se aprecia en el código de mi aplicación, tiene definido un atributo denominado *"fecnac"* del tipo *"java.sql.date"*, esto es, para recibir en el atributo *fecnac*  del tipo correcto *java.sql.Date*, el resultado que obtengo del *query* ejecutado contenido en la variable *"rs.getdate(Fecnac)"*.

Para estar seguro de los valores devueltos por el query, en mi código se puede obvervar que hice un "System.out.println a rs.getDate("Fecnac") (sin conversiones o formatos)" y de cada campo que contiene el dato de la supuesta fecha correcta, con la finalidad de asegurarme que la información obtenida del query, no es modificada por ninguna conversion o asignación incorrecta en otra variable de tipo diferente que pueda alterar su contenido...y en los tres obtengo el mismo valor de la fecha con un día menos.

Alguien podría orientarme que sucede ? estoy haciendo algo mal que ocasiona que se resta por si solo un día a la fecha al ejecutar el query? porque le resta un día? gracias y saludos !

Comment: Compañero, te comento que tu caso ya fue resuelto en otra pregunta similar, te comparto el link [¿Por qué Java le resta dos días a las fechas de SQL Server?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87237/por-qu%C3%A9-java-le-resta-dos-d%C3%ADas-a-las-fechas-de-sql-server)

Comment: Estimado @EdwinVasquez agradezco el tiempo que te tomaste para  ayudarme a encontrar una solución, sin embargo, tu respuesta sobre el enlace donde ya quedó resuelta mi pregunta, no corresponde a mi planteamiento. Yo no uso ningún variable **String** para recibir un dato del tipo **sql.date()**. Si revisas mi código, una vez ejecutado el query, verifico el resultado obtenido de la **columna Fecnac** de tres maneras y una de ellas es nativa: **System.out.println("QUERY DATE BY COLUMNLABEL:"+rs.getDate("Fecnac"));**, sin conversion, y el resultado es la fecha menos un día y no entiendo la razón.

Comment: Buenas Juan Carlos yo tengo el mismo problema pero con SQL y a mi me resta 2 días probare lo de "ServerTimezone".

Answer (score 4):

ya encontré la solución a mi problema y lo comparto porque pudiera ser de utilidad para alguien que experimente alguna situación parecida. Resulta que el comportamiento extraño que tenía mi aplicación respecto a que **le restaba un día a la fecha leída en una columna de una tabla de mi base de datos**, se debía a la incorrecta definición de la zona horaria que estaba usando en mi código en la variable *url*. Aquí el ejemplo:

```
public static Connection getMySQLConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/imss"+
            "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true"+
            "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=America/Mexico_City"+
            "&verifyServerCertificate=false"+
            "&useSSL=true"+
            "&requireSSL=true";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

Al momento de inicializar el parámetro de la zona horaria yo tenía definido el parámetro como: *serverTimezone=UTC*, pero luego lo ajusté correctamente como se aprecia en el código a: ***serverTimezone=america/Mexico_City*** que es la zona que me corresponde, y ¡listo! la fecha se muestra de manera correcta.

Comment: Correcto, regularmente entre sistemas cuando son temas de fecha es la configuración regional del equipo o bien la zona horaria definida, ya que esto ocurre en el handshake entre sistemas o aplicaciones, gracias por compartir

Saludos

Comment: Gracias Por Compartir tu Solución